# Set the child record foreign key to null while deleting the parent record in @OneToMany in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 entities, Department and Employees,one department can have many employees.Employee table has a foreign key, DEPT_ID.
I want to delete a particular department and set the foreign key to null for all the employees of that department.
Instead my code is deleting the child records(i.e employees) even though I just the DEPT_ID set to null.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence1")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence1", sequenceName = "SEQ_DEP")
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private long departmentId;
    
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_LOCATION")
    private String departmentLocation;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence2")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence2", sequenceName = "SEQ_EMP")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private long employeeId;
    
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
    private String employeeName;
    
    private int salary;
    
    private String email;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private Department department;

}

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Department department = session.get(Department.class, 3102l);
        List<Employee> list = department.getEmployees();
        for (Employee employee : list) {
            employee.setDepartment(null);
        }
        session.delete(department);
```

Note: I have enabled show_sql = true, and I can see that UPDATE queries are fired first for EMPLOYEE table which I think is setting DEPT_ID to null for all employees, and then I can see the DELETE query fired which deletes the Department record.

I am using Oracle database, and foreign key is defined as ON DELETE RESTRICT.

Answer (score 0):

Set employees to null in department object before deleting

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Department department = session.get(Department.class, 3102l);
        List<Employee> list = department.getEmployees();
        for (Employee employee : list) {
            employee.setDepartment(null);
        }
        department.setEmployees(null);
        session.delete(department);
```

Comment: Great.. Can you mark my answer as accepted??